# Node.js C++ addons: how to create JS Date object by N-API and V8 in Node.js 10

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

The `napi_create_date` function appeared in Node.js starting with 11.11.0 version.
https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_napi_create_date

Which workarounds are there to create JS Date (from C++ double) on Node.js 10.15.3 using N-API and V8 API only?

Or maybe I can get V8 Isolate from N-API?

Or how can I combine N-API and NAN to create Date and use it in `napi_call_function`?

I need some way to create a Date value (from C++ double) for `napi_call_function` call.

Answer (score 2):

For now I written such a workaround.
It is more correct to use `env->context()` instead of `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()`, but `napi_env` is defined in `src/js_native_api_v8.h`, which does not exist in `~/.node-gyp/10.15.3/include/node`, so I did not find a fast way to use `env->context()`.

```
#include <v8.h>

// This asserts v8::Local<> will always be implemented with a single
// pointer field so that we can pass it around as a void*.
static_assert(sizeof(v8::Local<v8::Value>) == sizeof(napi_value),
  "Cannot convert between v8::Local<v8::Value> and napi_value");

napi_status napi_create_date_by_v8(
    double time,
    napi_value* result
) {
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();

  v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> maybe_date = v8::Date::New(isolate, time);
  v8::Local<v8::Value> local = maybe_date.ToLocalChecked();
  *result = reinterpret_cast<napi_value>(*local);
  return napi_ok;
}
```